# How to save large output sufficiently fast in text or any other format?

Tags: r

My question is: how to save the output i.e., `mydata`

```
 mydata=array(sample(100),dim=c(2,100,4000))
```

reasonably fast?

I used the `reshape2` package as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474986/saving-a-multi-dimensional-matrix-to-a-file).

```
 melt(mydata)
```

and

```
 write.table(mydata,file="data_1")
```

But it is taking more than one hour to save the data into the file. I am looking for any other faster ways to  do the job.

Comment: `saveRDS` and `readRDS` will probably be the fastest way to save and load R objects.

Comment: `readr::write_delim(mydata, path="data_1")`

Comment: I'm working with genotyping data myself, these rows can contain about a million columns, if your case is anything like that you might consider writing per one or two lines and use `append = TRUE`

Comment: I haven't digested it myself, but you might find the discussion [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fast-csv-writing-for-r/) relevant (posted today).

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505605/speeding-up-the-performance-of-write-table), compares feather, fwrite, saveRDS

Comment: @nrussell. It is what I was looking for, very fast in both ways (save and read). Thank you very much.

Comment: @hrbrmstr. I am facing problem when installing the "curl " package in "readr" package.  My configuration failed for package ‘curl’. Will try again later with re-installation of r.

Comment: `fwrite` prbly also works (wasn't sure if it was in CRAN `data.table`). You need `libcurl` on your system if not running Windows for the `curl` pkg.

Comment: @hrbrmstr. Thanks. It is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly suggest to refer to this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370132/r-data-formats-rdata-rda-rds-etc), that surely helps in make issues clear about file saving.

Anyway, `saveRDS` could be the most adequate for you. The difference more relevant, in this case, is that `save` can save many objects to a file in a single call, whilst `saveRDS`, being a lower-level function, works with a single object at a time.

`save` and `load` allow you to save a named R object to a file or other connection and restore that object again. But, when loaded, the named object is restored to the current environment with the same name it had when saved.

`saveRDS` and `loadRDS`, instead, allow to save a single R object to a connection (typically a file) and to restore the object, possibly with a different name. The low level operability makes `RDS` functions more efficient, probably, for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Read the help text for saveRDS using ?saveRDS. This will probably be the best way for you to save and load large dataframes.

```
saveRDS(yourdata, file = "yourdata.Rda")
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the option `compress = FALSE`, otherwise you miss the speed benifits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even though it is working fast  without using compress = FALSE.